# All divs are overlapping

Tags: html, css, overlapping

Every div on my page is overlapping each other. My site is running on bootstrap 3.3.7.

The site is displaying everything that is above the header on the top of the site (on navbar). There is also a image under navbar maybe that is the proble.

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
}


/* Header */

.line-1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  width: 24em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  font-size: 180%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


/* Animation */

.anim-typewriter {
  animation: typewriter 4s steps(44) 1s 1 normal both, blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 19.2em;
  }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(28, 36, 65, 0.93);
  background: url('../img/head.png');
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 95%, 0 100%);
}

header .table {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

header .container {
  height: 100%;
}

header .header-text {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
}

header .typed {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

header .typed-cursor {
  font-size: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #00a8ff;
  -webkit-animation-name: flash;
  animation-name: flash;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


/* Navbar */

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #242c43;
  border-color: #242c43;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #0ca8fd;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #0ca8fd;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #242c43;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  color: #0ca8fd;
  background-color: #242c43;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li.divider {
  background-color: #242c43;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
  color: #0ca8fd;
  background-color: #242c43;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #0ca8fd;
  background-color: #242c43;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  color: #0ca8fd;
  background-color: #242c43;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #242c43;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #242c43;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #0ca8fd;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #ecf0f1;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    color: #0ca8fd;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
    color: #0ca8fd;
    background-color: #242c43;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Olesandr Kapitula</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End of navbar -->
  <!-- Header image -->
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="table">
        <div class="header-text">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
              <h3 class="light white line-1 anim-typewriter">HTML/CSS/JS/PHP WEBDEVELOPMENT</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- End of header image -->
  <!-- Panels -->
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End of panels -->


  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
RAW Paste Data

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Olesandr Kapitula</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End of navbar -->
  <!-- Header image -->
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="table">
        <div class="header-text">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
              <h3 class="light white line-1 anim-typewriter">HTML/CSS/JS/PHP WEBDEVELOPMENT</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- End of header image -->
  <!-- Panels -->
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End of panels -->


  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: one of your problems might be this: `<div class="table">`. You are using this class incorrectly, it is meant for `<table>` or an element representing a table of data. Its not meant for layout purposes.

Comment: @zgood it's not about this :/

Comment: also i've added paddin-top: 40px; to body and still nothing